# execve shellcode linux segmentation fault

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

Im trying to run this shellcode but it throws me: "Segmentation fault" error
The shellcode is the following:

shellcode.asm:

```
global _start
_start:

jmp short ca
doit:
pop ebx
xor eax, eax
cdq
mov byte [ebx+7], al
mov long [ebx+8], ebx
mov long [ebx+12], eax
lea ecx, [ebx+8]
mov byte al, 0x0b

int 0x80
ca:
call doit
db '/bin/sh'
```

i compile it with : 'nasm -f elf shellcode.asm'
and link it with: ' ld -m elf_i386 -s -o shellcode shellcode.o

I think the error is when I use mov [ebx+x], al/eax/ebx 
because when I erase it from the code y get no error

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the `.text` section is not writable by default. The easiest thing to do is put your code into a new custom section that is marked as writable. Add this line at the top of your asm file:

```
section .shellcode  progbits alloc exec write align=16
```

You could also pass the `-N` switch to the linker.

Alternatively, you could rewrite the shellcode so that it uses the stack to create the arguments.

Comment: Thank you , it works. Yes, if I use the stack, it works properly, but I wanted to know why cant I use mov [], x instructions.

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for hours. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this. The exec section didn't work but -N did. Cheers